# "Который" во фразе "человек, который съел машину"

Tags: синтаксис, части-речи, местоимения

Во фразе:

> человек, который съел машину

можно выделить такую синтаксическую структуру:

```
человек (какой?) -> который съел машину

который съел (основа придаточного предложения)
```

Получается, что *который* — это подлежащее в придаточном предложении.

При этом в словаре Зализняка слово *который* отнесено к *местоимению-прилагательному*.

**Вопрос:** каким образом прилагательное может реализовывать синтаксическую функцию подлежащего? Или для *мс-п* действуют какие-то особые правила, продиктованные спецификой местоимений?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Человек, который съел машину.***

Слово ***который***  ― союзное слово,  это его синтаксическая роль.

С  точки зрения морфологии ***который*** является местоименным прилагательным, но с точки зрения **синтаксиса** союзное слово **замещает опорное существительное** (определяемое слово в главной части, то есть слово ***человек***).

Союзное слово  выполняет **ту синтаксическую роль**, которую выполняло бы замещаемое им существительное  (человек) в придаточном предложении.

В данном случае это роль **подлежащего**.

Comment: Спасибо за развёрнутый ответ. Буду вам признателен, если прокомментируете вторую часть вопроса — https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/460852/%d0%9a%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%92%d0%be%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%8e-%d1%81%d1%86%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%83-%d0%b2-%d0%b3%d0%bb%d1%83%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%bd%d1%8b-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%81%d0%be