# "Который" в предложении "Вообразите огромную сцену, в глубине которой видны высокие холмы, почти горы"

Tags: синтаксис, части-речи, местоимения

Первая часть вопроса находится [здесь](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/460841/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B5-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BA-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%81%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BB-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83).

Рассмотрим предложение:

> Вообразите огромную *сцену*, в глубине **которой** видны высокие холмы, почти горы.

и сравним его с таким:

> Во мраке тёмной *пещеры* было по-прежнему тихо, лишь где-то в глубине **её** со свода падали в воду тяжёлые капли.

У словоформы *её* есть частеречная вариативность, позволяющая в зависимости от контекста отнести её либо к местоимению-существительному, либо к местоимению-прилагательному. Во втором из приведённых предложений *её*, как мне кажется, реализуется именно как *местоимение-существительное* (*р.п. от* она — её).

**Вопрос:** в чём принципиальное различие синтаксических ситуаций в первом и втором приведённых предложениях?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Синтаксис** у этих предложений разный: сложноподчиненное предложение (СПП) с придаточным определительным и сложносочиненное предложение (ССП).

В зависимости от содержания вы выбираете ту конструкцию, которая для вас удобна.

Надо отметить, что они **взаимозаменяемы**, но, безусловно, для второго распространенного предложения больше подходит именно ССП.

А это перестроенные предложения:

(1) ***Вообразите огромную сцену, в глубине ЕЁ видны высокие холмы, почти горы*** (БСП, бессоюзное сложное предложение).

(2) ***Во мраке тёмной пещеры, лишь где-то в глубине КОТОРОЙ со свода падали в воду тяжёлые капли, было по-прежнему тихо*** (СПП с придаточным определительным).

Второе предложение выглядит не лучшим образом и по структуре, и по содержанию, но поэтому мы и выбрали ССП.

Это то, что называется синтаксической синонимией. Автор в каждом случае подбирает то, что лучше подходит для конкретного содержания.

Таким образом, мы видим, что союзное слово ***который*** и местоимение ***ее*** вполне **взаимозаменяемы** по грамматическим характеристикам. В обоих случаях они играют роль **дополнения**, которая характерна для местоименного существительного..

Примечание. Я не уверена, что я правильно поняла ваш вопрос, но вы ведь скажете мне об этом.

Comment: Я именно хотел отделить словоизменительную составляющую от синтаксической и взглянуть на примеры с двух точек зрения. Ваш ответ прекрасно позволяет это сделать. Спасибо!

Comment: И вам спасибо! Вы всегда задаете очень интересные и нестандартные вопросы.